# How to set up a fancy header and title?

Tags: header-footer

I have a [LaTeX example](https://www.uncg.edu/cmp/faculty/srtate/495.f16/grading.pdf) that I'd like to replicate but I'm not quite sure how it's done. I managed to do it in Word (but that's boring and ugly!) so I figured I would post here to see if anyone had any hints on how to start it (it just looks really good and I'd like to replicate it with some of my own assessments). Thanks!

Comment: Before becoming downvoted because of a lack of any research effort, try something yourself, by using the fancyhdr package.

Comment: Nothing odd here. The title seems a standard `\title{foo}\maketitle` and the header could be done with a standard `tabular` (≠ table)  using `fancyhdr`. My advice is  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner).